# Evernote Windows SDK - How do I access the UserStore?

Tags: c#, evernote

Currently using the Evernote Windows SDK nuget package with C#. I'm able to connect and authenticate and can access the NoteStore data. However, I can't see how to access the UserStore data.

For clarification. I'm looking for the data held in the UserStore section mentioned here: https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/data_structure.php

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: turns out i was horribly wrong, you can use the UserStore but you can't authenticate to it. So we can't get all the good information but below is an example of code that works for me that gets username and shardid (the only info  i could get)

```
String evernoteHost = "www.evernote.com";
Uri userStoreUrl = new Uri("http://" + evernoteHost + "/edam/user");

// using the Thrift.protocol and Thrift.transport
TTransport userStoreTransport = new THttpClient(userStoreUrl);
TProtocol userStoreProtocol = new TBinaryProtocol(userStoreTransport);
UserStore.Client userStore = new UserStore.Client(userStoreProtocol);

// returns an EDAM type of user
var evernoteUser = userStore.getUser(authInfo.oauth_token);
```

According to the Evernote documentation, only internal applications are allowed to authenticate with the UserStore and from my research,

> This function is only available to Evernote's internal applications. Third party applications must authenticate using OAuth as described at dev.evernote.com.

https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/UserStore.html#Fn_UserStore_authenticate